# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined --javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create a calculator with javascript but I keep getting an error message of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined" on the console whenever I click on the number button. and at the same time, the number button is not displayed in strings. What am I doing wrong?

```js
//Javascript

class Calculator {
  constructor(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement) {
    this.previousOperandTextElement = previousOperandTextElement;
    this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement;
    this.clear();
  }
  clear() {
    this.previousOperandElement = '';
    this.currentOperandElement = '';
    this.operation = undefined;
  }

  delete() {

  }

  appendNumber(number) {
    this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString() + number.toString();
  }

  chooseOperation(operation) {

  }

  compute() {

  }

  updateDisplay() {
    this.currentOperandTextElement.innerText = this.currentOperand;
  }
}


const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]');
const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]');
const equalsButton = document.querySelector('[data-equals]');
const deleteButton = document.querySelector('[data-delete]');
const allClearButton = document.querySelector('[data-all-clear]');
const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-previous-operand]');
const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-current-operand]');

const calculator = new Calculator(currentOperandTextElement, previousOperandTextElement);

numberButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText);
    calculator.updateDisplay();
  });
});
```

```css
//CSS


*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Gotham Rounded, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #722f37, #caa181);
}

.calculator-grid {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: minmax(120px, auto) repeat(5, 100px);
}

.calculator-grid>button {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid white;
  outline: none;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
}

.calculator-grid>button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
}

.span-two {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.output {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  background-color: rgba(51, 35, 35, 0.397);
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.output .previous-operand {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.output .current-operand {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" , initial-scale=1.0>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Calculator</title>
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="calculator-grid">
    <div class="output">
      <div data-previous-operand class="previous-operand"></div>
      <div data-current-operand class="current-operand"></div>
    </div>
    <button data-all-clear class="span-two">AC</button>
    <button data-delete>DEL</button>
    <button data-operation>÷</button>
    <button data-number>1</button>
    <button data-number>2</button>
    <button data-number>3</button>
    <button data-operation>*</button>
    <button data-number>4</button>
    <button data-number>5</button>
    <button data-number>6</button>
    <button data-operation>+</button>
    <button data-number>7</button>
    <button data-number>8</button>
    <button data-number>9</button>
    <button data operation>-</button>
    <button data-number>.</button>
    <button data-number>0</button>
    <button data-equals class="span-two">=</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The only place you assign to `this.currentOperand` is in the line that you reference `this.currentOperand.toString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not initialize "currentOperand".

```
 constructor(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement) {
    this.previousOperandTextElement = previousOperandTextElement;
    this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement;
    this.currentOperand = "";
    this.clear();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

on the first button click, your `this.currentOperand` doesn't have any value, so it will be `undefined` variable. and `undefined` variable doesn't have toString property.
So the solution is, u need to put condition in that appendNumber function that if the variable is undefined, then the variable just filled by the `number.toString` like code below

```js
appendNumber(number) {
    if(this.currentOperand != undefined){
         this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString() + number.toString();
    }else{
        this.currentOperand = number.toString();
    }
}
```

or if you wanna make this simpler you can define the variable in the constructor, because basicly the error is caused by `Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined`, so we just need to change the variable at the first state, changeing undefined variable to defined variable with

```js
this.currentOperand = '';
```